# Three.js custom shader error on Chrome GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Active draw buffers with missing fragment shader outputs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, three.js, shader

I want to build a custom shader which will not be rendered. I mean I want to tell fragment shader not to write anything. So, on fragment shader I am not setting gl_FragColor.

The program works well on Firefox and Edge but not working on Chrome. On Chrome has warning: "GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Active draw buffers with missing fragment shader outputs."

Can you help me to solve this problem on Chrome? Is there any settings to accept shader without fragment?

vertexShader:

```
  void main() 
  {
    vec4 modelViewPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewPosition;
  }
```

fragmentShader:

```
  void main() {
    return;
  }
```

Comment: Why do you need a fragment shader that does not write anything? That seems not valid setup to me. BTW: I've created a live example with your shader code (https://jsfiddle.net/4fe9x1zk/1/). However, I get a different error message with Chrome (on macOS): GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: buffer format and fragment output variable type incompatible

Comment: @Mugen87 It is valid. If you only want to generate a depth map (e.g. light map) then the fragment shader can be empty. In this case the framebuffer consists of a depth buffer but no  color buffer. The depth is written automatically and the fragment shader has nothing to do at all.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think I found now a solution for this issue. If you set `Material.colorWrite` to `false`, the mentioned warning will be gone. Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4g2ok9na/. Let me post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you can avoid this warning by setting [Material.colorWrite](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/Material.colorWrite) to `false`. This will tell WebGL to disable all color components when your custom shader material is used for rendering.

`three.js R107`

Comment: Hi Mugen, thank you very much. Your suggestion is exactly and that is all what I need.

Comment: Great! Please accept/upvote the answer if it was useful to you.